# mysql update one field, replace first character

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name `tariff`, but now I want to replace values in column `service_code`

The values are like this:

```
D2P
D2D
D2D
D2P
D2D
```

What I want to achieve:

```
P2P
P2D
P2D
P2P
P2D
```

Just changing the 'D' to 'P' as first character

Comment: your column name has space in service code?

Comment: no, typo :p .. thanks for your answer

Comment: always welcome @may

Comment: @May what about when one More Record( servicecode) with value ''D2P1"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the below query:

```
    UPDATE tariff SET service_code=CONCAT('P', SUBSTRING(service_code FROM 2))
    where substring(service_code,1,1)='D';
```

or

```
UPDATE tariff SET service_code=CONCAT('P', SUBSTRING(service_code FROM 2))
        where left(service_code,1)='D';
```

Comment: I think your answer is not good because she wants to replace all for many rows

Comment: You can also use left(column,1) ='D' , substring is a bit overkill for this solution

Comment: Thank you lalithkumar.

It's working properly.

Answer (score 3):

**Use More Generic Query**

```
update tariff set service_code='P'+substring(service_code,2,len(service_code)-1)
where  substring(service_code,1,1)='D'
```